# filtering an array of objects based on a contained arrays contents. Vanilla JS, lodash, some other react releated technology?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

So i'm making a react app and I have a list of projects that use specific technologies.  I want the user to be able to be able to say i'm looking for a project that uses 'a', 'b', and 'c' technologies via some checkboxes (maybe) and the list of projects will automatically update.  Should i just be using vanilla javascript for this (to sort through an array of objects) or is there an easier way to do it?

If this should be done via vanilla javascript, can someone give me a little direction please. was able to do this successfully search for just one 'technology' but couldn't quite get it done searching for multiple technologies.

Example data to be below.

```
const projects = [{
  name: 'projecta',
  technologies: ['a', 'b', 'f'],
  link: 'www.example.com'
},
{
  name: 'projectb',
  technologies: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
  link: 'www.example.com'
},
{
  name: 'projectc',
  technologies: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  link: 'www.example.com'
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a destructuring while filtering with checking all wanted technologies.

```js
const
    projects = [{ name: 'projecta', technologies: ['a', 'b', 'f'], link: 'www.example.com' }, { name: 'projectb', technologies: ['c', 'd', 'e'], link: 'www.example.com' }, { name: 'projectc', technologies: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], link: 'www.example.com' }],
    search = ['c', 'e'],
    result = projects.filter(({ technologies }) =>
        search.every(s => technologies.includes(s)));
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice solution @Nina, but be aware that [**.includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) isn't supported by all browsers.

Comment: @chsdk, destructuring, neither, but op uses `const`, so it's ES6.

Comment: Yes maybe you are right about that, but I just mentioned it for others  ;)

Comment: @NinaScholz    wo  (⊙⊙)(☉_☉)(⊙⊙)  w nice

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple checkboxes you will get an array which contains the value of all selected checkboxes.
Filter the array based one or multiple values will work like this:

```js
const projects = [
    {
        name: 'projecta',
        technologies: ['a', 'b', 'f'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'projectb',
        technologies: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'projectc',
        technologies: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    }
];

const search = ['c', 'e'];

const result = projects.filter(project => {
  return search.every(s => project.technologies.includes(s));
});

// or

const result2 = projects.filter(project => {
  return !search.some(s => project.technologies.indexOf(s) === -1);
});

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: but he mentioned the relationship is "AND"ed, so I would expect an empty list in case of `a`, and `e`, unless he meant something else

Comment: I added an 'a' to the techs of the second project, i will fix it and use another search to test.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it using only vanilla JS, you can profit from [**Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)'s buil-in methods to do it.

You can use a combination of **[`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** methods to filter your array based on the specified technologies list.

This is how should be your code:

```
const techs = ['a', 'c'];
var filtered = projects.filter(function(p){
    return !techs.some(function(t){
        return p.technologies.indexOf(t) === -1;
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
const projects = [
    {
        name: 'projecta',
        technologies: ['a', 'b', 'f'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'projectb',
        technologies: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'projectc',
        technologies: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    }
];

const techs = ['a', 'c'];
var filtered = projects.filter(function(p){
    return !techs.some(function(t){
        return p.technologies.indexOf(t) === -1;
    });
});

console.log(filtered);
```

**Explanation:**

We use `filter()` method to loop over the array filter its elements and in its callback function we use `.some()` method to test over the iterated project `technologies` to make sure they're all among of the given technologies list.

Comment: Thanks for the solution... and the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you store the selected technologies in an array, you could simply loop through each project with `filter()` and return those that have at least one of the techs.

In the snippet below we iterate through each project with `filter`, meaning we create an array with items that satisfy the criteria in the callback.

The callback does another filter for each tech of the current project, and returns the length of the filtered array. If no tech of the current project matches your selection, the array length is zero which is a falsy value and the whole object won't be returned to the new array.

---

For example:

```js
let selectedTechs = ['a', 'b'];  //selected techs
const projects = [
    {
        name: 'projecta',
        technologies: ['a', 'b', 'f'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'projectb',
        technologies: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'projectc',
        technologies: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    }
];

let arr = projects.filter(
  (item) => item.technologies.filter((x) => selectedTechs.includes(x)).length
);

console.log(arr); //returns the 1st and 3rd project object.
```

---

and a demo in React:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      technologies: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
      checkedTechs: [],
      projects: [
        {
            name: 'projecta',
            technologies: ['a', 'b', 'f'],
            link: 'www.example.com'
        },
        {
            name: 'projectb',
            technologies: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
            link: 'www.example.com'
        },
        {
            name: 'projectc',
            technologies: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
            link: 'www.example.com'
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  
  checkTech = (name) => {
    let arr = this.state.checkedTechs.slice();
    if(arr.includes(name)) {
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(name), 1);
    } else {
      arr.push(name);
    }
    this.setState({checkedTechs: arr});
  }
 
  render() {
    let {technologies, checkedTechs, projects} = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
          {technologies.map(
            (item) => <label key={item}>{item}<input value={checkedTechs.indexOf(item)>-1} onChange={this.checkTech.bind(this, item)} type="checkbox" /></label>
          )}
        </div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.projects.filter(
           (item) => item.technologies.filter((x) => checkedTechs.includes(x)).length
          ).map(
            (item) => <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The above is to show project that **include** the selected techs. If you want to select projects that have **exactly** the selected techs, replace the filter logic with:

```
(item) => item.technologies.join(',') === checkedTechs.sort().join(',')
```

Comment: Nice solution but be aware that [**.includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) isn't supported by all browsers.

Comment: @chsdk, good point. This is for browsers supporting ES6 or if babel-polyfill is used.

Comment: I like this a lot thanks! Super clean code.  For this project it probably won't matter that .includes() isn't supported by all browers.

Comment: @D.Wall, glad you found it useful! I have added a sample code for a React implementation. Also, if this was helpful, please consider marking it as "accepted". Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript for this. Say, in each click of `checkbox` your checkbox value is saved in choice then you can get the objects like this,

```js
const projects = [
    {
        name: 'projecta',
        technologies: ['a', 'b', 'f'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'projectb',
        technologies: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'projectc',
        technologies: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        link: 'www.example.com'
    }
];

var choice = 'e';

var res= projects.filter((x)=>{
   if(x.technologies.indexOf(choice) !== -1){
      return x;
   }
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  this will only allow a search for one included technology though right?  Just 'e'.  I've come up with a solution below but i'm not sure it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found something that works.  best solution?

```
const checkFor = ['a', 'b'];
const winners = projects.filter(project => {

            return checkFor.every(function(val) {
                return project.technologies.indexOf(val) !== -1;
            });
        });

        console.log('winners: ', winners);
```

Comment: wow bunch of solutions up now to work with.  Thanks everyone who replied.  Will work through all of this.